# CakePHP 3 - phpUnit Webinterface?

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0, test-runner

where has the Webinterface for unittests in CakePHP 3 gone? There is no more test.php in the /webroot folder. Are tests only accessable by console now? That's not very comfortable!?

Thank you

Comment: I also find it very sad, but until someone provides a plugin bridge to re-enable it via VisualPHPUnit or alike there is nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the webrunner is gone, and it took the test shell with it into the abyss of outdated testing tools. Out of the box, CakePHP 3.x tests can only be run via the phpunit CLI runner.

> [...]
>
> The webrunner (`webroot/test.php`) has been removed. CLI adoption has
>   greatly increased since the initial release of 2.x. Additionaly, CLI
>   runners offer superior integration with IDE’s and other automated
>   tooling.
>
> If you find yourself in need of a way to run tests from a browser you
>   should checkout [**VisualPHPUnit**](https://github.com/VisualPHPUnit/VisualPHPUnit). It offers many additional features over
>   the old webrunner.
>
> [...]

From **[Cookbook > Appendencies > 3.x Migration Guide > Testing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#testing)**

Comment: Thank you - I'll give it a try.